# Programa que lea una matriz y determine si es concéntrica o no

Tags: python, c++

La verdad no tengo idea de como puedo hacer un programa que lea una matriz y determine si es concéntrica o no, por concéntrica se refiere a que sea una matriz de esta forma:

> ```
> 0  0  0  0  0
>
> 0  2  2  2  0
>
> 0  2  1  2  0
>
> 0  2  2  2  0
>
> 0  0  0  0  0
> ```

Y en la entrada se supone que un entero n seguido de una matriz cuadrada de `n×n` enteros, que `1 ≤ n ≤ 350` y que n es impar.

Lo único que se me ocurre sería una función booleana al final, 0 para falso 1 para positivo si es que la matriz cumple con los requisitos y los ciclos for para revisar y leer posiciones en filas y columnas.

El programa puede ser tanto en C++ como en Python

---

Se los agradezco muchisimo, viendolo objetivamente si cumple con que se construya la matriz, la lea y determine si es concentrica o no, primero voy a estar probando paso a paso sus respuestas propuestas y actualizaré si me surgen mas dudas

Comment: Saludos, por favor lee [ask] y de paso realiza el [tour], te comento que las preguntas que solo exponen el enunciado de una tarea sin mayor evidencia de trabajo así como dudas puntuales terminan cerradas

Comment: Haz una función que le "de vuelta" a la matriz recorriendola asi: fila 0, última columna, ultima fila, primera columna. Si hay elementos distintos, no es concentrica. Si son todos iguales, pela la matriz y repite el proceso más adentro, hasta llegar al centro.

Comment: Es un problema interesante. Sería una lástima que cerraran esta pregunta. Publica tu intento de respuesta para evitarlo.

Comment: Coincido con @candid-moe, es una situación curiosa de resolver. ¿Qué has intentado para resolverlo?

Comment: Si; no encuentro una solución que no sea trabajosa, larga y aburrida (Python).

Comment: Tengo una solución bastante escueta que es aplicable a matrices tanto numéricas como de texto, pero quiero ver la aproximación del OP y recopilar algo más de información. No reportaré la pregunta porque creo que puede ayudar a gente que explore soluciones de recursividad y de trabajo con matrices

Comment: Como pide solución en C++ o Python, entiendo que hay que hacerlo sin Pandas ni recursos externos.

Comment: O [tag:python] o [tag:c++], son lenguajes muy distintos y tendrán soluciones muy distintas.

Comment: Efectivamente sería sin recursos externos, con python limpio son 10 líneas de código

Comment: @CésarGonzález 10 lineas? Puedes compartir tu solucion? No se me ocurre como puede ser tan corto.

Comment: Lo tengo en 10 líneas de código.

Answer (score 2):

A falta de más información y tras hablarlo en los comentarios dejo una primera aproximación.

```
def check_matrix(matrix):
    elements = matrix[0] + matrix[-1]
    for x in matrix[1:-1]:
        elements += x[0], x[-1]
    if len(set(elements)) != 1:
        return False
    elif len(matrix[0]) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return check_matrix([x[1:-1] for x in matrix[1:-1]])
```

### Explicación

Recuperamos la primera y última fila de la matriz:

```
elements = matrix[0] + matrix[-1]
```

Con las filas restantes iteramos para recuperar el primer y último elemento de cada una de ellas:

```
for x in matrix[1:-1]:
    elements += x[0], x[-1]
```

En elements tendremos entonces una lista con los valores del perímetro de la matriz. Pasamos a comprobar si son iguales viendo la longitud de `set(elements)`. Si la longitud es distinta de 1 quiere decir que en ese perímetro hay valores no válidos y devolvemos un `False`

```
if len(set(elements)) != 1:
    return False
```

Comprobamos si estamos en la última capa (un único valor) y de ser así devolvemos un `True` ya que sólo hay un valor:

```
elif len(matrix[0]) == 1:
    return True
```

Si no estamos en la última capa volvemos a llamar al propio método pasando como parámetro la matriz recortando el perímetro:

```
else:
    return check_matrix([x[1:-1] for x in matrix[1:-1]])
```

### Cosas extra

Si queremos validar también que los valores de las "capas" son únicos deberíamos ir preparando una lista con los valores que nos vamos encontrando y comparar con el valor de la "capa" actual:

```
def check_matrix(matrix, values=[]):
    elements = matrix[0] + matrix[-1]
    for x in matrix[1:-1]:
        elements += x[0], x[-1]
    if len(set(elements)) != 1:
        return False
    if elements[0] in values:
        return False
    values.append(elements[0])
    if len(matrix[0]) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return check_matrix([x[1:-1] for x in matrix[1:-1]], values)
```

Y si además queremos que ese valor sea siempre inferior al número de capas podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
import math

def check_matrix(matrix, values=[], limit=None):
    if not limit:
        limit = math.floor(len(matrix[0])/2)
    elements = matrix[0] + matrix[-1]
    for x in matrix[1:-1]:
        elements += x[0], x[-1]
    if len(set(elements)) != 1:
        return False
    if elements[0] in values or elements[0] < 0 or elements[0] > limit:
        return False
    values.append(elements[0])
    if len(matrix[0]) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return check_matrix([x[1:-1] for x in matrix[1:-1]], values, limit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución recursiva para variar:

```
def es_simetrica(m, pos):
    """
    Determina si una submatriz es concentrica o no.

    :param m: Una matriz de nxn, n impar
    :param pos: Posicion sup. izq. de la submatriz a examinar (pos, pos)
    :return: True si es concentrica.
    """
    dim = len(m)
    # Revisar el borde exterior de la (sub)matriz
    for idx in range(pos, dim - pos):
        if not m[pos][idx] == m[dim - pos - 1][idx] == m[idx][pos] == m[idx][dim - pos - 1] == m[pos][pos]:
            return False
    # Revisar la submatriz interior restante. Si no, terminamos.
    return es_simetrica(m, pos + 1) if pos < dim // 2 else True
```

En la primera llamada, se examina la matriz completa (pos = 0 -> coord (0,0) de la matriz).

Primero se recorre el borde externo de la matriz chequeando que todas las celdas den el mismo valor. Si no, se retorna con `False` de inmediato.

Si pasó la primera prueba, se llama recursivamente para revisar la submatriz interior, que ahora tendría por esquina sup. izq. las coord (1,1). Por tanto, llamo recursivamente con la misma matriz y pos = 1.

**Comprobación matrices concentricas**

```
#--------- Matrices concentricas para probar -----------
matriz1 = [[1]]
matriz3 = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
]
matriz5 = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]
matriz7 = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 2, 2, 2 ,2, 0],
    [0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0],
    [0, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 0],
    [0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0],
    [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]

print("Matrices concentricas: ")
for m in [matriz1, matriz3, matriz5, matriz7]:
    print(es_simetrica(m, 0))
```

produce:

```
Matrices concentricas: 
True
True
True
True
```

**Comprobación matrices no concentricas**

```
#------------ Matrices no concentricas -----------
xatriz3 = [
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
]
xatriz5 = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 2, 2, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]
xatriz7 = [
    [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 2, 2, 2 ,2, 0],
    [0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0],
    [0, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 0],
    [0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0],
    [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]

print("Matrices no concentricas")
for m in [xatriz3, xatriz5, xatriz7]:
    print(es_simetrica(m, 0))
```

produce:

```
Matrices no concentricas
False
False
False
```